# Remove string from SQL column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a `TEXT` datatype field called "XMLText" in `SQL Server 2012`.  What I'd like to do is remove any `SageID` fields.  So this long string field contains something that looks like this:

```
<pair n="priorinstitution2" v="Yale School of Medicine" />
<pair n="priorinstitution3" v="" />
<pair n="sageid" v="20668528" />
<pair n="priorinstitution1" v="University of Chicago" />
```

What I'd like to do is remove everything for the `SageID` tag so that the final result is this:

```
<pair n="priorinstitution2" v="Yale School of Medicine" />
<pair n="priorinstitution3" v="" />
<pair n="priorinstitution1" v="University of Chicago" />
```

Obviously, it's not in a fixed position in the field and the v= could be any numbers or length.  What's the SQL string manipulation to do this?

Comment: One technique is to use a recursive CTE with PATINDEX() and STUFF() to remove all occurrences.

Comment: Does your SQL column contain one occurence of  `sageid` or multiple per row? **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421226)**

Comment: @Rabbit You can use STUFF to remove string fragments?

Comment: Stop using `TEXT` datatype which will be removed in future `Sql server` versions. Use `XML` datatype to store **xml** data

Comment: @TabAlleman You can use STUFF to replace a section of a string with a blank string. You just need to use PATINDEX or CHARINDEX to find the section of the string you want to remove.

Comment: @lad2025: I agree with VR46, even though there's no root element.  It's still XML data...just poorly formed.

Comment: @DMason Yup still XML so modify will work.

Comment: Yes, it's a full XML string in the field.  I just pulled out a snippet showing the relevant areas for my question.  I know Text is deprecated, but it's what we have for now.  Moving it over to an XML data type is ideal, but unfortunately out of my control at this time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`TEXT` is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). Store your `XML` chunks as `XML` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)`.

You can use `xml.modify` and [`delete`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190254.aspx) to remove multiple occurences at once:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(id INT, col TEXT);

INSERT INTO #tab(id, col)
VALUES 
(1, '<pair n="priorinstitution2" v="Yale School of Medicine" />
     <pair n="priorinstitution3" v="" />
     <pair n="sageid" v="20668528" />
     <pair n="priorinstitution1" v="University of Chicago" />')
,(2, '<pair n="sageid" v="2" y="adsadasdasd"/>
      <pair n="priorinstitution2" v="Yale School of Medicine" />
      <pair n="priorinstitution3" v="" />
      <pair n="sageid" v="20668528" />
      <pair n="priorinstitution1" v="University of Chicago" />
      <pair n="sageid" v="2066852832421432" z="aaaa" />');


SELECT *, xml_col = CAST(col AS XML)
INTO #temp
FROM #tab;

UPDATE #temp
SET xml_col.modify('delete /pair[@n="sageid"]');

UPDATE t1
SET col = CAST(t2.xml_col AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
FROM #tab t1
JOIN #temp t2
 ON t1.id = t2.id;

SELECT *
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421256)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that your XML data is not well-formed (no root element).

**EDIT:**

If your XML Text has different structure and you want to  find all `pair` element with attribute `n="sageid"` use:

```
UPDATE #temp
SET xml_col.modify('delete //pair[@n="sageid"]');
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/421269)**</kbd>

Comment: this is nice solution

Comment: @techspider This will work, but OP should fix his schema.

Comment: true... that's the basic expectation... you did a great job, though!

Comment: @techspider Probably OP has some legacy code and needs to live with it. And that's why we need to develop workarounds to keep things working. And one day the technical debt be so high that it will have to collapse :)

Comment: Agreed, very nice solution/workaround.  STUFF might work too, but it's problematic if the "XML" data isn't in a consistent pattern/format.

Comment: @DMason Then the OP should provide better(more descriptive) sample and then change the XQuery expression.

Comment: Did you misunderstand my comment?  Or am I misunderstanding yours?  I was trying to pay you a compliment.  :)  Working with the data as an actual XML data type and using `.modify()` is less error prone than trying to use `STUFF` with VARCHAR data (which was proposed elsewhere).

Comment: @DMason I misunderstand your comment :(. Anyway I added some edit to handle case where `pair` is anywhere in hierarchy (see demo2). So thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Not a great solution but to find positions of start and end of tag and replace it with a blank string

```
UPDATE YourTable 
SET yourColumn = REPLACE(yourColumn, SUBSTRING(yourColumn, CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', yourColumn), CHARINDEX('/>', yourColumn, CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', yourColumn)) - CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', yourColumn) + 2), '')
```

Adding below script for debugging

```
DECLARE @str AS VARCHAR(255) = '<pair n="priorinstitution2" v="Yale School of Medicine" /><pair n="priorinstitution3" v="" /><pair n="sageid" v="20668528" /><pair n="priorinstitution1" v="University of Chicago" />'

SELECT REPLACE(@str, SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', @str), CHARINDEX('/>', @str, CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', @str)) - CHARINDEX('<pair n="sageid"', @str) + 2), '')
```

Comment: would you consider split that big line in diferent parts?